# How to remove double quotes inside double quotes in string field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Currently a document looks like this:

```
  {
    "Post": "this is a post",
    "_id": ObjectId("630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"),
    "iframe": ""https:/www.youtube.com/embed/RzVvThhjAKw"",
    "slug": "this-is-a-title",
    "title": "This is a title"
  }
```

But I want it like this:

```
{
    "Post": "this is a post",
    "_id": ObjectId("630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"),
    "iframe": "https:/www.youtube.com/embed/RzVvThhjAKw",
    "slug": "this-is-a-title",
    "title": "This is a title"
  }
```

How to remove double quotes inside double quotes in iframe string field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `update` the document in the collection, here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0")
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "iframe": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$iframe",
          // find every double quote ...
          "find": "\"",
          // ... and replace it with nothing
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZnkfduUKlGJ).

Answer (score 0):

For aggregate query, you can work with `$regexFind` to capture the match group.

1. `set` - Set `iframe` field.

   1.1. `$first` - Get the first item of array from the result *1.1.1*.

   1.1.1. `$getField` - Get the `captures` array field from the result of *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$regexFind` - Return a regex object result from matching the `iframe` value with provided regex expression.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      iframe: {
        $first: {
          $getField: {
            field: "captures",
            input: {
              $regexFind: {
                input: "$iframe",
                regex: "\"([^\"]+)\""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5lO8Bml2zsx)

---

You may use `$ifNull` operator to remain the existing `iframe` value if it doesn't match the regex expression.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      iframe: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $first: {
              "$getField": {
                "field": "captures",
                "input": {
                  $regexFind: {
                    input: "$iframe",
                    regex: "\"([^\"]+)\""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "$iframe"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo with `$ifNull` @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6P2id2nG_uO)